# Way to ensure that my antivirus is flagging a false positive

Tags: anti-virus, gaming

So I recently bought Tom Clancy's [Splinter cell](https://store.steampowered.com/app/13560/Tom_Clancys_Splinter_Cell/) and [Splinter cell: Chaos theory](https://store.steampowered.com/app/13570/Tom_Clancys_Splinter_Cell_Chaos_Theory/) on Steam. While the games work perfectly, as soon as I run them, my antivirus flags them as keyloggers and blocks them(you know where I am getting at), thus disabling all inputs to the game(except the arrow keys, which aren't prudent to be used in conjunction with a mouse).

The issue is easily solved by disabling my antivirus' anti-keylogger feature, but, I am concerned about the off chance that my antivirus is flagging a truly malicious app(no offense ubisoft)

I run a Windows 10 machine with [Quick Heal](https://www.quickheal.com/quick-heal-total-security) being my antivirus.

So, I have 2 questions-

1. Has anyone else faced this problem too?
2. If yes, what were your findings(i.e. was this game safe, or is there something fishy here?)

Thanks for answering

Comment: The game you've mentioned, has 1833 reviews on steam and is present since 2003. And, paid software doesn't usually have malwares hidden in them. This makes me feel like the game can be trusted. Also, [some other people](https://steamcommunity.com/app/13570/discussions/0/1290691308575880243/?l=french) also faced this issue, while using QuickHeal

Comment: Thanks a ton @SaaranshGarg.. I am going to either disable quick heal for the time being or..use a [keybinder](https://www.autohotkey.com/).. Could you please type this comment as an answer, so that I can mark it..

Comment: [Quick Heal Total Security review](https://www.pcworld.com/article/402181/quick-heal-total-security-antivirus-review.html) is not enthusiastic. Use [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) to compare to other antivirus products.

Comment: Splinter Cell Chaos Theory contains (or contained) invasive copy protection measures (StarForce). This could trigger your AV protection.

Comment: My rule of thumb for antiviruses… the more frequently they want to remind you of how much care they're taking of you, the more you should be worried about the quality of that care ;)

Comment: hmmm.. @Tetsujin that concerns me about my antivirus now..(shouldn't have brought that 3 year plan :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game you've mentioned, has 1833 reviews on steam with its overall review being very positive and is present since 2003(Stats for [Splinter Cell](https://store.steampowered.com/app/13560/Tom_Clancys_Splinter_Cell/)). And, paid software doesn't usually have malwares hidden in them. This makes me feel like the game can be trusted. Also, [some other people](https://steamcommunity.com/app/13570/discussions/0/1290691308575880243/?l=french) also faced this issue, while using QuickHeal.

Answer (score 4):

[Quick Heal Total Security review](https://www.pcworld.com/article/402181/quick-heal-total-security-antivirus-review.html) is not very enthusiastic.

The best way to check for a false positive by your antivirus is to check
the flagged file using the website
[Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload),
to compare with many other antivirus products.
If none of the main antivirus products flags your file, you may
ignore the warning as being a false positive.

Comment: The OP says that the game gets flagged as a keylogger "as soon as I run them". Scanning such a file is unlikely get flagged as a malware. Also, He/she has an entire game, which isn't easy to be scanned on VirusTotal because of its 650 MB file limit.

Comment: @harrymc would you recommend a good antivirus, which can perform better than my current one? Thanks..

Comment: Windows Defender costs nothing and its scores today are among the best in the latest [AV-Test benchmark](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/).

Comment: hmm.. @harrymc I have been at the receiving end of these malwares, and windows defender is good, but not enough... any paid options that are highly rated(not dreaded like idk.. McAfee for example?)

Comment: Windows Defender has much improved lately, I don't use anything else now. You could always take your pick according to the AV-Test.